# Point label position (MS chart c#)

Tags: c#, charts, position, label

I want to make such that my series point label is showen outside the chart, in the buttom hand side of the series (see picture below)

[image]

Right now the label is showing in the middle:

[image]

The series is a `RangeBar` with `Pointwidth = 5` to which i set the folloing SmartlabelStyle:

```
var series2 = new Series
            {
                Name = "S2",
                Color = Color.LightGray,
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar,
                ChartArea = "boo",
                YValueType = ChartValueType.Auto,
                XValueType = ChartValueType.Auto,
                SmartLabelStyle = new SmartLabelStyle 
                 {
                   AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes,   
                   IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = false, 
                   MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.Bottom
                 }
             };
```

Than I simply add a data point:

```
minDate = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 000);

// Dummy data
var values2 = new DateTime[6];
values2[0] = minDate.AddMonths(1);
values2[1] = minDate.AddMonths(2);

// Add point.
pointIndex = series2.Points.AddXY(values2[1], values2[2]);

series2.Points[pointIndex].AxisLabel = "Laa";
series2.Points[pointIndex].Label = "Laa";
```

How should I set the **Point label** to be showen in the **bottom hand side**?

Comment: [Msdn:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.smartlabelstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) SmartLabelStyle is not supported for RangeBars.

Comment: Do you know a work around?

Comment: Drawing in the PostPaint event is hard as we don't know the coordinates for bar and column types. You can add TextAnnotations..

Comment: Is it possible to show me an example what exactly you mean? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wish I could but frankly I don't know how to quite achive the effect you want :-(